Is it still necessary to specify "defaultBranch = main" in Git configuration?
I remember that a few years ago, Git used 'master' as the default branch name. However, I no longer have any projects on my GitHub profile that use 'master.' All my projects are now created with 'main.' In this case, is it still necessary to include the line defaultBranch = main in the .gitconfig file?

I believe that the update you speak of (master > main) was just a change to the config file, so you need it exactly as much as you did before the change.

Pedantic point, a local instance of git doesn't really have a concept of a "default" branch only an "initial" branch, as long as you create/switch to a new branch before your first (public) push, the public repo will not see the initial branch anyway. That said, the initial branch is labelled "default" in the commands, even though it's really just an initial branch.

Do you mean init.defaultBranch?
If you would like a new repo created locally to automatically use main as the default branch, yes. But, if you always create a new repo from GitHub's UI, this setting doesn't matter.
As far as I know, git didn't change the default settings away from master (as of version 2.47.0), while GitHub did.

Yes, this is the case for the current version at the time of the question (2.47.0).  Git service platforms are changing, but the primary git client has not.
